# Virtual key code of ALT KEY

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

I am making hooks and catching keyboard virtual key codes, according to MSDN,  [these are](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) the key codes that exist.

Every key code works fine as i will give an example down below of my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

HHOOK altKey;
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdHK;
MSG message;

LRESULT CALLBACK kbdProc(int nCode, WPARAM wPar, LPARAM lPar);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  altKey = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, kbdProc, NULL, 0);

  while(GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) > 0){
    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessage(&message);
  }
  return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK kbdProc(int nCode, WPARAM wPar, LPARAM lPar){

  if(nCode >= 0){
    if(wPar == 256){
      kbdHK = *(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lPar;
      if(kbdHK.vkCode == 0x20){
        printf("spacebar pressed!!\n");
      }
    }
  }
  return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wPar, lPar);
}
```

But when I replace the virtual key code with `0x12` which is ALT KEY according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), I can't get a result back. What could be the problem?

**Edit**:

When I use this line of code, I can get the `scanCode` for every key but not for alt key again which is interesting.

```
printf("%d", kbd.scanCode);
```

Comment: downvoter, please tell me the reason for the downvote.

Comment: I am not the down voter, and I have run your code, but will not debug.  Have you considered using a WinAPI function to detecte keystrokes?  ( See _[GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)_ )

Comment: @Sebivor I have removed the C tag, sorry about that. Maybe that was the reason why it got downvoted

Comment: @ryyker I have thought about it, and I am thinking it will probably work that way, but I wanted to use `vkCode`, if i can't find a solution I will have to switch to it.

Comment: A console mode app is the wrong kind of app to test this.  The console host (conhost.exe) gets a crack at keystrokes first, it treats Alt special since it operates the console itself instead of the program.  Try Alt+Space for example.  Build a native windows program instead.

Comment: btw - just because code uses winapi, does not disqualify it from also being C.  Your code, just as it is built and ran in my ANSI C compiler.  It is therefore C.  It is more likely the down voter was responding to a request for help debugging your code.  i.e. there is nothing detectably wrong with it, it behaves as expected, but you just cannot get it to do what _you_ expect.    The close vote listed _off-topic_ as the reason.  I do not agree, but then the down voter does not need me to.  Personally I think it is a good question, and could probably be helpful to others in the future.  (+1)

Comment: @ryyker but still, i have a question. This all code is C code and the libraries are its own, still, what's wrong with tagging C?

Comment: @Sebivor what is wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing - re-read my last comment:  _just because code uses winapi, does not disqualify it from also being C. Your code, just as it is built and ran in my ANSI C compiler. It is therefore C._

Comment: yes I commented the question right after that comment before reading it @ryyker

Comment: You just need to avoid the unix crowd,  [winapi] is safe.

Comment: @ryyker A question that contains C code does not necessarily need the C tag. This code could've been C++, instead, and you would've had the same problem. The problem is independent of the language, and bound to the Windows API. The question is asking about a problem with the Windows API.

Comment: @turmuka See above.

Comment: very true, it's probably about the type of the app @HansPassant I will test it on other ones and will let you know

Comment: @Sebivor - Never asserted a requirement, simply disagree with the exclusion of a tag because it is also other tags.  The OP code is still C after all, even though it is also winapi and hook, and any other appropriate tag that can reach a broader audience. (Oh, and as long as there are only 5 or less of them)

Comment: I agree @ryyker but I can pretty much imagine what could happen if I add C tag in the question again, I would receive more reactions. Just call it SO community :). It's not like I am posting python code and tagging C. and people of knowledge with C can still see and acknowledge the question, even though they don't know winapi very well, they can still learn from this question, and I guess this is what makes better community.

Comment: i mean it's just weird i think this is way too personal but most people on SO would agree with you, so that's why I removed the tag. There is no formula to what's right and what's wrong. you are also right at some point too @Sebivor

Comment: @ryyker The purpose of tags is not to reflect the contents of the question, but to aid people who have the same problem in the future in finding this question (and thus any answers). Does adding the C tag do so? They might have the same problem in C++ or assembly, instead... Should we add those tags (and code), too? Or should we have separate questions for those (with **identical answers** and identically functioning fragments of code, in different languages, of course)? Does that seem sensible to you?

Comment: @ryyker: `GetAsyncKeyState` queries the momentary state of a key corresponding to a virtual-key code. It cannot detect keystrokes.

Comment: @IInspectable - From MSDN: GetAsyncKeyState _Determines whether a key is up or down at the time the function is called, and whether the key was pressed after a previous call to GetAsyncKeyState._ By observing these state changes, a keypress can be detected.  It is common to implement this function in a loop so changes in state, or even combinations of keys being pressed simultaneously can be detected.

Comment: @ryyker: `GetAsyncKeyState` is sample-based. A reliable way to monitor keystrokes requires an event-based implementation. `GetAsyncKeyState` can very well miss keyboard input when it happens in between sample points. My comment still holds: You cannot use `GetAsyncKeyState` to monitor keystrokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest hooking [the `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646286(v=vs.85).aspx), and noting that the values correspond to constants that more often have identifiers (`VK_MENU`, in this case). After all, as programmers we're taught early on *not to use magic numbers*!

> WM_SYSKEYDOWN message
>
> **Posted to the window with the keyboard focus when the user presses** the F10 key (which activates the menu bar) **or holds down the ALT key and then presses another key.**

Another option, as pointed out in the comments, is to use [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx). Your concerns that you won't be able to use *`vkCode`* seem strange, as `GetAsyncKeyState`s parameter *is* the virtual key code, after all, so the code you'd be using would be along the lines of:

```
short result = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU);
if (!result) {
    // no alt keystrokes since last call
}
```

This is the only way you'll be able to distinguish between left alt (`VK_LMENU`) and right alt (`VK_RMENU`) keys, but it's *not the window-loop way*. Now you have both.